# Randomization of the array modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, particles

I would like to create something that is basically what array modifier does, but with a tiny bit of randomization (of both location and rotation). The particle system would be otherwise fine except that it is too random. I couldn't find a way to make the particles mostly organized with a little bit of randomness.

I found a really old patch to Blender introducing exactly what I wanted, but apparently it was never accepted: https://developer.blender.org/T26662.

EDIT: I used the method suggested by Faceb Faceb below to get the following result:[image]

The result is fine, but in this method I have to apply the array modifier before randomization which makes it more difficult to e.g. change individual parts of the array later (if I wanted to, for instance, fiddle with the shape or looks of the bricks in the picture above). If there is a way to achieve this result using the particle system, I'm interested.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain and illustrate what type of randomisation you need and how far you got with using a particle system for this as I think a particle system is what most people will recommend.

Comment: maybe apply the array modifier, separate loose parts, then origin to center of mass and then manipulate the center points with random falloff?

Comment: Not possible. Use animation nodes addon: https://youtu.be/M8x0YMbixC0

Comment: It is impossible with the current *Array* modifier alone. It might be possible using Duplifaces and applying them, or using a particle system instead.

Comment: I created a quick example showing what I want to achieve using the method suggested by Faceb Faceb: http://imgur.com/7dPo7dM . This method works fine, but it is not very optimal because I have to apply the array modifiers before randomization.

Comment: If you add a plane, subdivide it, then poke the faces, you can add a particle system that emits from the vertices to get the organization you want.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work because there is no way to emit only one particle per vertex. If I just keep increasing the particle count, particles are randomly assigned to vertices and sometimes I get several particles on the same vertex.

Comment: Actually you can, you just set the number of particles to the number of vertices. You can use hair particles, or emitter particles if you set the frame start/end to 1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Result with *Particle System*

[image]

---

### Preparation

- Create an *Object* (Cube) and bring it in the desired shape.
- Create a *Plane*, subdivide it in *Edit Mode* (<kbd>F6</kbd> for adjusting the number of cuts easily).
- Add a *Particle System* to the Plane.

---

### Setting up the Particle System

1. In the *Physics Dropdown* choose **No**.
2. In *Render Dropdown* choose **Object** and pick your "brick" you have created.

   [image]

---

3. In the Emission Dropdown choose:

   - Emit from Faces
   - Grid
   - Enable Hexagonal Grid

   [image]

---

4. Play around with the *Resolution* value in the *Emission Dropdown* and scale <kbd>S</kbd> your Plane along one Axis until you have a nice Pattern.

   [image]

---

5. Randomize:

   - In the Emission Dropdown you can add a random Offset to the Grid locations
   - Enable the Rotation Dropdown and randomize softly the Particle Orientation

   [image]

Comment: With version 2.79 I had to include the following step within: **Setting up the Particle System** 2.1 Enable *unborn* and *died* in the Render dropdown.